# Van der pauw method for an isolated hole

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics, conductors

Van der pauw method is a way to measure the resistivity of a material with arbitrary shape while it meets some specifications ( being homogeneous and ...).
One of the conditions is that the sample must not have any holes.

How can the van der pauw method be applied for samples with holes?

Comment: If the shape doesn't change, you can measure a sample with and without the hole and and calculate a correction factor.

Comment: how can we find the correction factor?
samples with holes, have different resistivity in different parts of the sample due to their distance to hole

Comment: Take the ratio between the two measurements and then you can use the same correction factor on your samples. I would try this with a range of samples to see how well it can be reproduced.

Comment: Sorry, do you have a miliohm meter?

Comment: Personally? Yes, actually, I do, but even if I didn't, I would know how to make one. Since you are asking I did, of course, assume that you have the right equipment.

Comment: sorry you said even if you didn't have, you'd know how to make one???
HOW???

Comment: With a lock-in amplifier. A circuit that is as simple as they come is shown here: http://cappels.org/dproj/dlmom/dlmom.html. Here is another one:http://www.electronics-lab.com/low-ohm-meter-measures-0-001-up-to-1-999-ohm/. OTOH, you can find really cheap ones on eBay these days... so why bother?